# Cannot run Ubuntu (touch) Facebook App

Tags: ubuntu-touch, facebook, qml, qt-creator, qt5

as said in the title, I'm not able to run and try Facebook App, such as it happens in the reported (not by me) bug #1226770
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-facebook-app/+bug/1226770

The application seems to be slowly developed, in fact it hasn't been upgraded for a while. As described in the bug, it affects youtube and twitter too.
Is that a real bug or what? I followed instructions of libraries to install but it was useless. The error is still:

/ubuntu-facebook-app/ubuntu-facebook-app.qml:74 ToolbarActions is not a type

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We stopped development on all of those apps. We may restart in future, but nobody is currently working on them.